# My administration menu dissapears when installing a module

Tags: routes, hooks

I have created a module that implements `hook_menu()` using the following code:

```
function mypbm_menu() {
  $items['pbg'] = array(
    'title' => 'Theming example',
    'description' => 'Examples of implementing theme functions.',
    'page callback' => 'pbg',
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );
  return $items;
}

function pbg($id) {
  $stringit = $id;

  return $stringit;
}
```

The module works the way it is supposed to work; when it is turned on, the [Administration menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module disappears.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Could be something else, maybe something in a theme function in your module? Also, are you clearing caches? If you look at your page's markup (HTML), do you still see the admin menu links added somewhere? It doesn't seem your hook_menu should interfere with admin_menu...

Comment: I had a similar issue, even filed a support request http://drupal.org/node/1553208. Although later on I found out a new config setting for admin_menu that caches the menu locally. I'm observing it now. unchecking it seems to have helped.

Comment: On another note, even though you're the only one using your callback function, it's still good practice to namespace everything.

Answer (score 1):

The reason in my case was the character encoding of the "mymodule.module" file. 
Changing it back from "UTF-8" to "ANSI" solved the problem.